# What would cause Cannot create user, email: invalid!! on an civicrm integrated webform?

Tags: webform-civicrm

When submitting a webform (links below) on our site, an error message is generated: Cannot create user, email: invalid!!

This error message displays for all webforms and for all email addresses, whether it is a valid email address or not.

In only one of the forms listed below should a drupal user be created. The other two forms are only intended to add people to mailing lists.

What should I be looking at to help understand this?

Webform for Mailing list only:

https://www.jewishideas.org/resources-educators

https://www.jewishideas.org/newsletters-0

Webform should be adding a free membership, so a user record is desired:

https://www.jewishideas.org/university-membership

Comment: Hi, I had a look and could be your field settings. You could try the ticking the 'Existing Contact' box on the Civi tab (should then change from id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-fieldset-fieldset-civicrm-1-contact-1-email-email"  to id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-email-email" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_email_email].

Comment: I also tried it with and without the "Existing Contact" checked in the Civi Tab on he webform per Rebecca's comment above

Answer (score 1):

I had the Rules module updated and removed all unused rules(of which we had many), and now the forms are submitting without error

Comment: I am having the same problem. This is on a new setup of the Rule to Create Drupal Users.  I did have 2 unused Rules that I deleted per LaurynnLowe's answer, but I still have the same error message.  I am getting 2 Drupal Log messages that might help trouble shoot this.                           
rules 08/16/2020 - 20:39 Unable to get variable civicrm_user, it is not defined. 
civicrm_entity 08/16/2020 - 20:39 Cannot create user, email invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a test submission.  The double exclamation point is interesting - that's not a string (`invalid!!`) that appears anywhere in the CiviCRM codebase.

This looks like a Drupal webform - I would check the settings on the webform for that text.  After that, it could be a Drupal module, or even a CiviCRM extension, but it's most likely webform-level validation settings.