# Cannot create Drupal user, email: invalid!! (double exclamation is the error message, not my urgency)

Tags: webform-civicrm, tags

Drupal 7.72
Civi 5.24.5
Webform Civi Integration 7.5.1

I just set it up so that Drupal users are created when a webform is submitted. Using [petednz's guide](https://civicrm.org/blog/petednz/creating-drupal-users-made-easy-single-or-multiple-contacts-civi-imports-and-webforms).

But I get the following error message Cannot create user, email: invalid!!

[What would cause Cannot create user, email: invalid!! on an civicrm integrated webform?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/34122/what-would-cause-cannot-create-user-email-invalid-on-an-civicrm-integrated-w) This has the same problem. I tried both suggestions there and it did not fix it for me.

I get the following 2 messages in my Drupal logs:

1. rules 08/16/2020 - 20:39 Unable to get variable civicrm_user, it is not defined
2. civicrm_entity 08/16/2020 - 20:39 Cannot create user, email invalid.

I use CiviRules to add a tag to the contact when a new contact is added from "these" Sources. Should the tag be added in a different manner? The guide was not clear on how to add the tag to the contact. I'm wondering if the Rules is firing before CiviRules gets the tag added.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach now is https://civicrm.org/extensions/silent-user-registration so you only use CiviRules and don't use Drupal Rules.

Comment: I tried the extension but it is not working for me. I posted a new question on that issue here https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/37444/getting-drupal-error-messages-with-silent-user-registration-extension