# Getting Drupal error messages with Silent User Registration extension

Tags: extension, cms-integration

Drupal 7.72
Civi 5.28.2
Silent User 1.0
I just installed the extension and setup the CiviRule per the pics on GitHub. My CiviRule trigger is a new contact created with condition of "these" sources (sources are webform civi integration forms that we use for contributions).

When I make a contribution as a new user, I get 2 Drupal error messages [image]
The contribution does process in Civi and it does include a Name and Email. But a user is not created in Drupal.
I added a 3 minute delay in the CiviRule and tested it with and without rechecking the condition. Now it does not show the Drupal errors as above but it still does not create a Drupal user.

In the Civilogs I see this (I assume it is related) [warning] Report Error Extension could not send since no email address was set.

In the Drupal Logs, I had the following
Notice: Undefined index: template_id in CRM_Emailapi_CivirulesAction_Send->userFriendlyConditionParams() (line 122 of /sites/default/files/civicrm/extensions/org.civicoop.emailapi/CRM/Emailapi/CivirulesAction/Send.php).

But I no longer get the log errors since I added the delay.

Comment: Hey @IowaBoy - I'm the author of this extension.  Open an issue on my Github?  I haven't tested with Webform - regular contribution/event pages require an email.  Does your Webform require an email?

Comment: Yes, an email is required. I posted it on Github

Comment: I just setup a new webform integration and noticed something that might help. The name and email information are on the first page of the webform. The payment information is on the second page and it only asks for the billing address. Maybe because the email is not on with the billing information it does not see the email field???

Comment: I tested moving the civicrm_1_contact_1_contact_first_name , last_name, and civicrm_1_contact_1_email_email to the second page of the form with the billing information. I still get the error message as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got some help from a friend and we got it working. The problem seems to be that the database was not finished writing to the email table when the CiviRule fires. We switched the rule to Trigger on "Email is created".